# Running ASP.NET from hosting process

Tags: asp.net

I'm responsible for a .NET process running under windows.
The process is running as a windows service.

I would like to have the ability to be able to get some info from the service in a web browser.
For that matter I would like to write a small ASP.NET web service.
The problem is that I want the run the web service within my process.
As far as I know, I can't do that since ASP.NET must run from within an IIS.

so...my question is, is it possible to host ASP.NET server within another process?

I know that in the common scenario, I should have the "process code" run as "code behind" the ASP.NET but in my case, the .NET service is already a part of our product so in this case I'd like to have the opposite.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to host ASP.NET inside your service. You can use inter-process communications techniques to communicate between your service and a new or existing ASP.NET webapp. [Here's an example using named pipes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/dotnetnamedpipespart1.aspx). [Or if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher you can use WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx).

If you really want the service to host its own site I don't think embedding ASP.NET is possible but you can use [an http component like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/http.aspx).

Comment: +1. Also if he's using .net 4.0, built in ipc would be more efficient than wcf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for replying. I thought of this option but that means that I'll have to run IIS on the server and I'd like to avoid this option.

Comment: Ah in that case you may want to just have your service listen on port 80 and serve up content. Added a link to an embedded http server component for .NET

Comment: Well, currently, looks like what I'm going to do. I wanted to avoid the dynamic http code but I guess no other option. Thanks a lot.